# How to pass model with child collection to partial view ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a MVC application. 
I want to pass the model's child collection from one view to another.

Please check below View Model.

I have below view model.

```
 public class AdviceCreateVM
        {      
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string AdviceNo { get; set; }
            public  ICollection<InvoiceVM> Invoices { get; set; }
         }


   public class InvoiceVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, consider below view of the AdviceCreateVM (Parent View)

```
    @model epay.ViewModel.AdviceCreateVM

    <h2 style="font-size:22px;margin-left:10px;"> New Payment Advice</h2>

     @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdviceCreate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmCreate", onsubmit = "disableSubmitButton()" }))
     {
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.AdviceNo ,new{@placeholder="Type No if any"})
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.AdviceNo )

   @{
      -->   Model.Invoices.Add(new epay.ViewModel.InvoiceVM());
   }
        @Html.Partial("AdviceInvoiceView", Model.Invoices[0],new ViewDataDictionary {{ "Count", a }})                    

    }
```

In above view (AS Arrow shown) , I want to pass the model with epay.ViewModel.InvoiceVM() which is child collection with single object to partial view  AdviceInvoiceView

How can I use the model with child collection in the partial view ?

Partial view code start with

```
@model epay.ViewModel.InvoiceVM
```

Is this correct ?

Comment: It should work, but what are trying to accomplish here? why are you creating a new model inside your view? You could also use a custom template instead of a partial view.

Comment: Ya, I stuck there...how to use passed model instead new one ?

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, you always have one `InvoiceVM` inside your `AdviceCreateVM` model. Why not automatically build it either in the constructor of your `AdviceCreateVM` model or within the controller, before calling your base view? Then you will be able to call the partial just like you already do.

Comment: You really should be using an editor template for `InvoiceVM` (or use a `for` loop in the main view) so the the input names are properly indexed for post back. Using a partial view like this will result in `Invoices` being null on post back.